# Android-XMPP disconnect

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack, disconnect

I'm using aSmack and Openfire for my application. And Spark for testing.

I'm writing my connection code and broadcast receiver which listen network state in STICKY service.

When i turn off my wifi, internet goes off but Spark still show me as 'Available' and after 3-4 minutes it turns my status to 'unavailable'.

I tried xmppConnection.disconnect() and Presence.Type.unavailable. But none of them working for me.

How can i instantly disconnect XMPP server / send presence 'Unavailable' after disconnecting client's internet connection ?

This is my code:

```
// Connect XMPP Server
public void connectXMPPServer() {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Create a connection
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
            connConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);

            xmppConnection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {

                xmppConnection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Connected to "
                        + xmppConnection.getHost());
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {

                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                        + xmppConnection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
            }

            try {

                if (xmppConnection.isConnected()) {

                    xmppConnection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Logged in as "
                            + xmppConnection.getUser());

                    Presence presence = new Presence(
                            Presence.Type.available);
                    xmppConnection.sendPacket(presence);
                }
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {

                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                        + USERNAME);
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

// Broadcast receiver; listens to network state
public BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {

            if (isNetworkOn()) {

                Log.i("BackgroundService-BroadcastReceiver",
                        "Network is on");
                connectXMPPServer();
            } else if (!isNetworkOn()) {

                Log.i("BackgroundService-BroadcastReceiver",
                        "Network is off");
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
                xmppConnection.sendPacket(presence);
                xmppConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("BackgroundService-networkStateReceiver", e.toString());
        }
    }
};

// Returns network state
public boolean isNetworkOn() {

    ConnectivityManager connMngr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connMngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
}
```

Comment: after internet connection goes off, your packets are not delivered / reach to server so it's shows continuously presence on the server. Use ping-pong for end-to-end connection, send ping after 30 seconds continuously to the client from server. if ping not receive from server then set presence unavailable to that user

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a ConnectionListener, which will get called as soon as connection drop is detected.  You can update your state in the UI then.

Sending presence is for letting others know your state, which you obviously cannot do if you have no connection.  The server will do this for you when it detects the disconnection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to know what can i do with the server so that it will show me as 'unavailable' as soon as client's internet connection goes off.

Comment: @Sushant have you gotten an answer or solution to the problem yet?